# How to determine the boot drive on a mac?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I need to determine inside my app which of the internal drives in my Mac is the boot drive. I am not sure if there is any specific property of the drive or any specific file that can help me uniquely identify the internal boot drive. 'diskutil info ' command gives a 'Bootable' property of the slice, but that property is not good enough as that property is being returned as true for multiple slices of a single drive or for all the drives.

Comment: This question probably belongs on the Superuser exchange, http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "bless" command, e.g.

```
$ /usr/sbin/bless --info --getBoot
/dev/disk0s2
```

See "man bless" for more information. With the "--plist" argument, the output can easily be parsed into a `NSDictionary`, the following sample code demonstrates this:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/bless"];
[task setArguments:@[@"--info", @"--getBoot", @"--plist"]];
NSPipe * out = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:out];

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];

NSFileHandle *read = [out fileHandleForReading];
NSData *data = [read readDataToEndOfFile];
NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:0 format:NULL error:NULL];
NSLog(@"output: %@", plist);
```

*Output:*

```
{
    "Boot Volume" = "/dev/disk0s2";
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:                                  Can't access "efi-boot-device" NVRAM variable

Comment: @Mriganka: I tested the code and it worked for me. Did you try it on the command line?

Comment: mriganka$ bless --info --plist
Can't access "efi-boot-device" NVRAM variable

Comment: That's the output that I am getting when I run it on the command line. Moreover, my requirement is to find the internal boot drive while I am booted from an external drive.'

Comment: What kind of Mac and which OS version do you have? I checked with two different Macs (iMac and MacBook Pro) and with 10.7 and 10.8.

Comment: There are a lot of Google hits for "Can't access "efi-boot-device" NVRAM variable", perhaps something helps. - Sorry that my solution did not work for you.